# Setup IP and port forwarding in AWS

Tags: port-forwarding, amazon-ec2, aws

I have a web server in AWS EC2 for example with http://11.22.33.44 listening to port 80. I would like to do something like port forwarding such as if I'm browsing the website IP from my home network using http://11.22.33.44:8001, it forward/translate the traffic to port 80 in my AWS server and browse my web site.

How can I do it in AWS? I just need to apply this rule for any source traffice from my home network, but in other network environment, it should still browse to http://11.22.33.44 port 80.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking for port 8001 to only be accessible from your local network (reject all other traffic) or are you asking for port 8001 to point to something different when accessed inside your local network?

Comment: hi @PhilipCouling, to make it clear, i have a AWS web server (centos 7) with IP http://11.22.33.44:80 , I have another server at Google Cloud with public IP 55.66.77.88. My scenario is if I'm browsing http://11.22.33.44:8001 from my Google Cloud server, I'm able to view the web content just like http://11.22.33.44:80, I think it's something called port forwarding if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a web server like Apache or Nginx. After successfully setting up you can write a rule for forwarding you port on local IP.
Here are some good reference for setting up web server:-

Apache=> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart

Nginx=> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart